# Unable to write file

Tags: matlab, file-permissions

I'm trying to write an image in `MATLAB`, but got the following error:

> Error using imwrite (line 455) Unable to open file "D1.bmp" for
>   writing.  You may not have write permission.

Why is that? How can I go around this error?

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, it would seem that you do not have permission to write the file where you are trying to save it. Make sure that you are not trying to write to a protected area of the computer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is a folder at my desktop. I checked the permissions, and it seems that I have full control. I have even moved my work to be at the desktop itself, but having the same issue

Comment: Does the folder exists? According to [this](http://www.mathworks.com.au/support/solutions/en/data/1-APY5VN/?solution=1-APY5VN) you may also get this error if the path to the file you specified does not exist.

Comment: Yes, the folder does exist. Please check my answer on how I managed to solve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If changing the filename but not the location fixed this problem, it's possible that you had an existing file, "D1.bmp", which was inaccessible for Matlab to write to, possibly because it was open in another program.

In some cases (dependant on Matlab version, I think - can't reproduce on this computer) this can happen just from having the directory open in Windows Explorer. See, for example, [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-DQPRHC/index.html) (Mathworks Support link).

If you want to avoid accidentally overwriting images, you can use `exist` to check if a filename is already in use, and if so change the filename (i.e. go to D2.bmp or D1_01.bmp), rather than changing the image format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I changed the extension of the written image to `jpg` instead of `BMP`.

Comment: Documentation: 

"If A is of data type logical, then imwrite assumes the data is a binary image and writes it to the file with a bit depth of 1, if the format allows it. BMP, PNG, or TIFF formats accept binary images as input arrays." BMP is not supported in any other case, probably matlab was trying to write a D1.BMP.jpeg

Comment: They're saying BMP/PNG/TIFF formats are the only ones that accept binary images, not that BMP can only write binary images. `imwrite` does 8-bit or 24-bit bmps as well.